# How to convert date to general format in Alteryx?

Tags: date, int, date-format, alteryx

Can you please tell how I can convert date to General format (as we have in Excel) please?

Basically I am looking for Date-INT(Date) in Alteryx.

Comment: Please provide some examples with input and expected output. By the way you simply shouldn't worry about how a date is represented behind the scenes. If you want to format it for display, use `DateTimeFormat`, but that will return a fornatted display *string*, no longer a Date. Within Alteryx just leave it as a Date or DateTime until you need that display string.

Comment: As an example we have 43862.0028140046 as general form of 01/02/2020 00:04. I need something like that in Alteryx and also Int function.

Comment: Just leave it as a DateTime. I believe int() just truncates to the date? If so, just making it a Date should truncate the time.

Comment: The Integer part of your example (43862.0028140046) is the number of days between 1899-12-31 and the date you have +1 to correct for 1900 not being a leap year. So the equation would be 
DateTimeDiff('1899-12-31',[DateField],'days')+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula  - DateTimeAdd("1900-01-01",[Field Name],"days") in formula tool to extract the date.
 Also you should subtract the date in general format by '2' before processing as excel computes 1900 as leap year.

[Alteryx Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88dPL.png)